# optimizing a rails query that's using collect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to optimize a query I'm making to get all tags on a collection of objects but I need help. Currently using collect to gather all the tags but looking at the logs I'm seeing basically 500 calls being made out and would like to see if a single query could do it.

```
@answers = Answer.limit(500).sort_by(&:plusminus)
@tags =  @answers.collect {|answer| answer.tags}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `join` instead

```
Answer.joins(:tags).select('answers.some_field, tags.some_field')
```

It will query only one time and will return an array or results

Comment: Nice, I knew it was something easy. Thanks!